# Improving SEO for a web

Tags: seo, google-search-console

I am a beginner in SEO and I have a website with this structure:

`/es/index.php
/es/clases.php
/es/horarios.php
/es/tarifas.php
/es/contacto.php
/es/login.php`
 and I have it three times: one for the directory /es/, one for /en/ and another one for /cat/. What I want to do in google is something like this:
[image]

I want to index the web by directories like this and all the files which are in it exept login.php. It's possible to do this with the google search console, html and robots.txt?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up Robots.txt to ignore login.php

```
    User-agent: *
    Disallow: /es/login.php
```

User-agent is for all crawlers, if you are only concerned with google, it should be 
        User-agent: googlebot

Other than this, google will crawl all pages on website subject to other things being correct.

Comment: Thanks, and how do i can organize the links like the image?